# Code of memmove()

Tags: c, memmove

The below code snippet shows the implementation of `memmove()`.

```
void my_memmove(void* dest, const void* src, size_t size)
{
    unsigned int i;

    char* d = (char*)dest;
    char* s = (char*)src;

    if( s > d )
    {
            for( i = 0; s[i] && i < size; ++i )
                    d[i] = s[i];
    }
    else
            for( i = size-1; d[i] && i >= 0; --i )
                    d[i] = s[i];
}

int main()
{
    char my_str[] = "abcdefgh";

    char str[] = "abcdefgh";

    my_memmove(my_str+1, my_str, 4);

    memmove(str+1, str, 4);

    printf("%s %s\n", my_str, str);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the [output](http://ideone.com/5oIQQ) as:

```
 aabcdfgh
```

Why my_memmove() is not working correctly ( It changes the my_str such that it outputs empty string )?

Comment: This must be a homework assignment, as this is the second copy of this question so far. Meanwhile, why on earth are you comparing pointers for > or < in here?

Comment: Also, why the null check with `s[i]`? You already have a size.

Comment: @bmargulies it affects the direction of the loop.  memmove must be safeguarded against overlapping memory.

Comment: null check with s[i] is used to handle the too large size. What if size is 50?

Comment: @Aashish: **nothing** can handle a wrong function argument. If your users *want* to break your code, they *can*. Document your function, and let your users worry about using it correctly.

Comment: @bmargulies I guess the intention is that the copy works for overlapping chunks of memory. If the overlap is at the top of your chunk, start copying at the top, otherwise start copying at the bottom.

Comment: I think the defects in this code would become clear to you if you step through its execution in a debugger. Do that - it will be a better learning experience than having SO explain it to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an **unsigned** integer, the condition `i >= 0` is always true. It's better to write the idiomatic loop with the "-1" reversal bias:

```
for (i = 0; i != size; ++i)
    d[size - i - 1] = s[size - i - 1];
```

Also, the additional condition `s[i] &&` just looks plain wrong.

Comment: It can also be written as `while (size--) d[size] = s[size];`

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that src and dest are pointing
to points in the same memory block.

```
...
char* d = (char*)dest;
char* s = (char*)src;

if( s > d )
...
```

This means if anyone ever calls your function with src and dest pointing to 2 different locations in memory, you will get undefined behavior.

This is very very bad, just use the built-in memmove().